# About Jpeg Compression Coeffients for image compression

Tags: image, jpeg, dct

Using JPEG 8*8 compression coefficient table in my work. Can anybody help me to know how these coefficients are derived? The formula? and also what about 4*4 coefficients and 16*16 coefficients?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to the quantization coefficients.

1. The size was determined by computational practicability at the time. You could get better compression with larger blocks but 8x8 was considered the best practicable size. If it were standardized now, it is possible larger blocks would have been used.
2. The coefficients can be any value greater than zero. The JPEG standard has a same set. The Defense mapping agency has standard sets. They come from experimentation. What gives the best compression with the least loss of image quality.